# Put awk output into variable while refactoring

Tags: bash, awk

I'm parsing website and some part of awked data should be written in variable:

```
grep -o -E 'Date:.*Name'|sed -e 's/Date:/|/g' -e 's/Type/|/g' -e 's/Name/|/g'| awk -F '|' '{print $3"|"$1"|"$2}'
```

and only last awk should be written in variable.

Tried simply:

`body=$(awk -F '|' '{print $3"|"$1"|"$2}')| echo $body` - empty output

Comment: [Checkout “END” in awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html).

Comment: You don't need grep or sed when you're using awk. If you post some concise, testable sample input and expected output we can help you.

Comment: I'm parsing big amount of data, it's just part of request, awking in the end is simply for changing order of data before loading to file. Maybe it can be done with awk, but it will be more complicated... for me)

Comment: No, it wouldn't be more complicated, it'd be clearer and more efficient. For example `sed -e 's/Date:/|/g' -e 's/Type/|/g' -e 's/Name/|/g'| awk -F '|' '{print $3"|"$1"|"$2}'` can be written as just `awk -F'Date:|Type|Name' -v OFS='|' '{print $3, $1, $2}'`. I didn't include the grep part as I'd just be guessing without sample input/output but I expect including that would be trivial too.

Answer (score 0):

```
body=$(awk -F '|' '{print $3"|"$1"|"$2}')| echo $body
```

will give empty out put since `|` creates a subshell and executes the `echo $body` in subshell. To make it display the value of `body`, change it into:

```
body=$(awk -F '|' '{print $3"|"$1"|"$2}'); echo $body
```

Proper way to achieve the desired goal is using command substitution:

```
variable=$(grep -o -E 'Date:.*Name'|sed -e 's/Date:/|/g' -e 's/Type/|/g' -e 's/Name/|/g'| awk -F '|' '{print $3"|"$1"|"$2}' )
```

Alternatively you can use read to get the value but you cannot use it outside subshell.

```
grep -o -E 'Date:.*Name'|sed -e 's/Date:/|/g' -e 's/Type/|/g' -e 's/Name/|/g'| awk -F '|' '{print $3"|"$1"|"$2}' | read body; echo $body
echo $body #will give empty here since the value of body existed only in subshell
```